Cannot emulate React-Leaflet's distance calculation
I am using react-leaflet and having issues with displaying the correct distance between two points.
When a user clicks on the map, a point is placed and then when hovering away from the point a tooltip appears with Leaflet’s calculation of the distance between the point placed down and the cursor.
I want to re-create this calculation no matter the number of points the user has placed down since leaflet’s calculation is the total distance from point A to point B to point C, etc.
However, my calculation always seems to be wrong, and I suspect for some reason off by one render?
In the image below, my cursor is moving away from the point placed in the top left, with Leaflet’s calculation above and mine below it.
Image #1
And when doing the opposite, moving my cursor towards the point, Leaflet’s calculation is shorter.
Image #2
I don’t know if I simply haven’t followed a hook / state rule, or whether this is an issue with how react-leaflet works. My code starts with defining two state variables to store the coordinates received from the useMapEvents hook.
const [clickCoord, setClickCoord] = useState<LatLng | undefined>(undefined);
const [cursorCoord, setCursorCoord] = useState<LatLng | undefined>(undefined);

These state variables are set using the useMapEvents hook as follows:
    useMapEvents({
        click(e) {
            setClickCoord(e.latlng);
        },
        mousemove(e) {
            setCursorCoord(e.latlng);
        },
    });

The distance between the two points is then calculated:
const { readableDistance } = L.GeometryUtil;
clickCoord && cursorCoord ? readableDistance(clickCoord.distanceTo(cursorCoord), true) : "ERROR"

And the result used in a function ‘getTooltipString’ which simply makes sure the distance is a string and adds the correct coordinates to that string. The result of that function call is then assigned to the lower text of the tooltip mentioned earlier that leaflet displays.
useEffect(() => {
        L.drawLocal.draw.handlers.polyline.tooltip = {
            start: 'Click to start drawing line',
            cont: getTooltipString(),
            end: getTooltipString(),
        };
    }, [clickCoord, cursorCoord, getTooltipString]);

Yet again, my distance is always off. I suspect this is my code having values which are one render behind react-leaflet's, but am not 100% sure where that issue would be arising from.
I would imagine this has to do with how I have set up my use of state, useEffect, and useMapEvents. I have attempted to move the storage of clickCoord and cursorCoord out of state and into a plain object, both inside and outside the component in which the rest of the code is. Still, I either get no change or lose the tooltip updating altogether.
